# What is the term for the little viewing window with a sliding cover in a castle or convent?

Tags: single-word-requests, architecture

You encounter them periodically in movies, and, in certain places, in real life. I asked people who live in a region positively studded with castles, and all they could come up with was "the peeping slidy thingy in the entrance door."

Which is amusing but doesn't answer the question.

What's it called? And the slide - does it have a separate term? [image]

Comment: Possibly a **hatch** with a **shutter** but I can't get the dictionary definitions. BTW were the spikes on the portcullis really necessary?

Comment: Googling, hatch seems the best option. Spyhole, peephole, etc suggest a hole without a cover. I can't find anything authoritative, just a bunch of forum posts.

Comment: In modern terms, I would call it a peep window: [`front door with peep window`](https://www.google.com/search?q=front+door+with+peep+window). Are you looking for a medieval/historical term?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Probably not. I found the picture on the web - took the first one that suited my purposes here. They seem to be purely decorative since they don't cover the entire entrance.

Comment: @TimR: Factual info would be better.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: I'm looking for the official architectural term. Historical or otherwise.

Comment: The sides of the portcullis are hidden by the shape of the archway; I'm sure it _does_ have spikes all the way across, to catch any attacker who might be trying to get in just as the portcullis was being lowered.

Comment: @WeatherVane Haha I just assumed that was so if the person behind the door saw somebody they didn't like they could just drop the spikes on them... :-D

Comment: It's not much use on an English-speaking site, but the word in French for this is a 'vasistas'. It comes from the German 'Was ist das?' (meaning 'what is it'). I know it sounds like this is something I've made up, but it is absolutely true. Have a look at https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/vasistas for a little more detail.

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking: This is fascinating. I'm not kidding.

Answer (score 12):

I believe the most common term would be a ***peephole***, even when talking about historical architecture. The one with a sliding cover could be called a *sliding peephole*.

[image] 
A medieval door with a peephole covered in metal bars. 
<sub>Photo by shutterstock.com / BonnieBC 

[*traditionalbuilding.com*](https://www.traditionalbuilding.com/product-report/door-additions)</sub>

---

***Speculatorium*** is a historical architectural term for it but it is not used today. It has the same etymons as *speculate*, a current word you are familiar with, which are Latin *speculāri* and its participal stem *speculāt-*. *Speculārī* means "to spy out, watch, examine, observe" and it comes from Latin *specĕre* "to see, look". The suffix *-orium* can form nouns with the sense "an instrument with which a specified activity is carried out".

The term is listed in the book *[Illustrated Dictionary of Historic Architecture](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Illustrated_Dictionary_of_Historic_Archi/kp_DAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22speculatorium%22%20architecture&pg=PA498&printsec=frontcover)* by Cyril M. Harris:

> **speculatorium** a peephole with a grating in a door for inspecting visitors.

For example, *speculatorium* was used in an architectural illustration of the door of S.George's Chapel in Windsor, in the book *[Metal-work and its artistic design](https://archive.org/details/gri_33125012901787/page/136/mode/2up)* by Wyatt, M. Digby, from 1852:

[image]

Comment: Yes; even the modern tiny lensed variety often has a hinged cover on the inside.

Comment: The wikipedia article for [peephole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole) suggests that this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

It might be called a **Judas window** or **Judas hole**. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/judas-window) has

> **judas**
> a peephole or a very small window in a door
> Also called: **judas window**, judas hole

---

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Judas_window) has

> **Judas window**
> A window enabling a prison guard to see into a cell without being seen by the prisoner.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336310/what-is-the-origin-of-judas-gate

Comment: Hmm... I think Judas Window applies only to the case of a prison cell rather than to the case depicted by the asker.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes called a **speakeasy window**.

Examples can be found at [Google Images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=speakeasy+window&tbm=isch&sclient=img).

In the prohibition era, they were commonly used on the doorways to speakeasy bars, and a patron would often have to whisper a secret password through the window before being allowed to enter the establishment.

Today, they are often used for ornamental effect, and perhaps in the doors of some nightclubs so that the security staff can engage with visitors safely.

Comment: Have you supporting evidence? Google images returns hits in a search for "speakeasy radiator".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it does, and those products don't seem to be about "speakeasy radiators", but the individual search terms. In the link I showed, manufacturers are describing their window-in-a-door as a "speakeasy window". Therefore it is a term which is being used. [One such](https://brennancorp.com/blog/whats-a-speakeasy-window/) was the source for a sentence in the answer.